# Byte Buddy Generated class not visible to Orika (Javaassist)

Tags: java, byte-buddy, orika

I use [Byte Buddy](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy) to generate some DTO classes in a Spring Boot application. I also use the [Orika](https://github.com/orika-mapper/orika) mapper librarie to map Entity to/from DTO classes. This library uses another runtime code generation tool to generate mapper classes, which is [Javassist](https://github.com/jboss-javassist/javassist).

My problem is that the Orika mapper that is supposed to map to/from classes generated by Byte Buddy is not able to find them. The exception is thrown at this [line in the Orika JavasssistCompilerStrategy class](https://github.com/orika-mapper/orika/blob/master/core/src/main/java/ma/glasnost/orika/impl/generator/JavassistCompilerStrategy.java#L172).

I'm not sure what happens here since the `Class<?> type` parameter is not null. Here's how my DTO class are generated:

```
final ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();

// This object holds the information required to generate classes
// for a use case (it also contains information about a generated
// @Repository, @Service and @RestController)
final DynamicBeansDefinition def = ...
// Create the DTO class from the entity class
final Class<?> entityClass = ClassUtils.forName(def.getEntityClassName(), classLoader);

final Builder<BaseDto> dtoBuilder =
      new ByteBuddy().subclass(BaseDto.class).name(def.getDtoClassName());

// Copy all the entity class properties (excluding inherited fields),
// adding @JsonView(Views.Public.class) on each field.
final Field[] fields = entityClass.getDeclaredFields();
for (final Field field : fields) {
  dtoBuilder
      .defineProperty(field.getName(), field.getType())
      .annotateField(
          AnnotationDescription.Builder.ofType(JsonView.class)
              .defineTypeArray("value", Views.Public.class)
              .build());
}
final Class<?> dtoClass = dtoBuilder.make().load(classLoader).getLoaded();
```

I tried (but not insensively) to create a ByteBuddyCompilerStrategy for Orika, which would be a nice and clean solution, but I was unable to create fields and methods from string representation of them, like it is done in [Javaassist](https://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/html/javassist/CtField.html#make-java.lang.String-javassist.CtClass-). Orika holds a generated class definition in the [SourceCodeContext](https://github.com/orika-mapper/orika/blob/master/core/src/main/java/ma/glasnost/orika/impl/generator/SourceCodeContext.java) class, which contains only source code (string representation) for fields and methods.

**EDIT**

Here's a quick representation of the (non-dynamic) base classes and interfaces. It will be a long post, but maybe it could help someone else in the future:

```
  @MappedSuperclass
  public class BaseEntity {

    @Id private Long id;
    @Version private Long version;

    // Getters and setters omitted for brevity
  }

  @Entity
  public class SomeEntityA extends BaseEntity {
    // Fields, getters and setters omitted for brevity
  }

  @Entity
  public class SomeEntityB extends BaseEntity {
    // Fields, getters and setters omitted for brevity
  }

  public class BaseDto {

    @JsonView(Views.Summary.class)
    private Long id;

    @JsonView(Views.Summary.class)
    private Long version;

    // Getters and setters omitted for brevity
  }

  @NoRepositoryBean
  public interface BaseRepository<E extends BaseEntity> extends JpaRepository<E, Long> {
    // Methods omitted for brevity
  }

  @Repository
  public interface SomeRepositoryA extends BaseRepository<SomeEntityA> {}

  @Repository
  public interface SomeRepositoryB extends BaseRepository<SomeEntityB> {}

  public interface BaseService<E extends BaseEntity, D extends BaseDto> {
    // Methods omitted for brevity
  }

  public class BaseMapper<E extends BaseEntity, D extends BaseDto> {

    private SomeRepositoryA someRepositoryA;
    private SomeRepositoryB someRepositoryB;

    protected BaseMapper(SomeRepositoryA someRepositoryA, SomeRepositoryB someRepositoryB) {
      super();

      this.someRepositoryA = someRepositoryA;
      this.someRepositoryB = someRepositoryB;
    }

    // Implementation omitted for brevity
  }

  public class BaseServiceImpl<E extends BaseEntity, D extends BaseDto>
      implements BaseService<E, D> {

    private BaseRepository<E> repository;
    private SomeRepositoryA someRepositoryA;

    protected BaseServiceImpl(BaseRepository<E> repository, SomeRepositoryA someRepositoryA) {
      super();

      this.repository = repository;
      this.someRepositoryA = someRepositoryA;
    }

    // Implementation omitted for brevity
  }

  public class BaseController<E extends BaseEntity, D extends BaseDto> {

    private BaseService<E, D> service;

    protected BaseController(final BaseService<E, D> service) {
      super();

      this.service = service;
    }

    // Implementation omitted for brevity
  }
```

Now, I would like to be able to generated the DTO, Repository, Mapper, Service declaration, Service implementation and RestController from an entity class. For example, from this:

```
  @Entity
  public class FooEntityA extends BaseEntity {

    @Column private String columnA;

    // Getters and setters omitted for brevity
  }
```

I want to generate this:

```
  public class FooDtoA extends BaseDto {

    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private String columnA;

    // Getters and setters omitted for brevity
  }

  @Repository(value = "fooRepositoryA")
  public interface FooRepositoryA extends BaseRepository<FooEntityA> {
    // WILL ALWAYS BE EMPTY, everything is defined in the base interface
  }

  @Component(value = "fooMapperA")
  public class FooMapperA extends BaseMapper<FooEntityA, FooDtoA> {

    public FooMapperA(SomeRepositoryA someRepositoryA, SomeRepositoryB someRepositoryB) {
      super(someRepositoryA, someRepositoryB);
    }

    // WILL ALWAYS BE EMPTY, everything is defined in the base class
  }

  public interface FooServiceA extends BaseService<FooEntityA, FooDtoA> {
    // WILL ALWAYS BE EMPTY, everything is defined in the base interface
  }

  @Service(value = "fooServiceAImpl")
  public class ServiceAImpl extends BaseServiceImpl<FooEntityA, FooDtoA> implements FooServiceA {

    public ServiceAImpl(
        @Autowired @Qualifier(value = "fooRepositoryA") BaseRepository<FooEntityA> repository,
        SomeRepositoryA someRepositoryA) {
      super(repository, someRepositoryA);
    }

    // WILL ALWAYS BE EMPTY, everything is defined in the base class
  }

  @RestController(value = "fooControllerA")
  @RequestMapping(path = "fooPathA")
  public class FooControllerA extends BaseController<FooEntityA, FooDtoA> {

    public FooControllerA(
        @Autowired @Qualifier(value = "fooServiceAImpl") BaseService<FooEntityA, FooDtoA> service) {
      super(service);
    }

    // WILL ALWAYS BE EMPTY, everything is defined in the base class
  }
```

And here's the method trying to do that (feel free to point out parts that could be better):

```
  public void createBeans(
      final ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory, final BeansDefinition def) {

    final ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();

    try {
      // Create the DTO class from the entity class
      final Class<?> entityClass = ClassUtils.forName(def.getEntityClassName(), classLoader);
      // final Class<?> dtoClass = ClassUtils.forName(def.getDtoClassName(), classLoader);

      final Builder<BaseDto> dtoBuilder =
          new ByteBuddy().subclass(BaseDto.class).name(def.getDtoClassName());

      // Copy all the entity class properties, adding
      // @JsonView(Views.Public.class) on each field.
      final Field[] fields = entityClass.getDeclaredFields();
      for (final Field field : fields) {
        dtoBuilder
            .defineProperty(field.getName(), field.getType())
            .annotateField(
                AnnotationDescription.Builder.ofType(JsonView.class)
                    .defineTypeArray("value", Views.Public.class)
                    .build());
      }
      final Class<?> dtoClass =
          dtoBuilder
              .make()
              // .load(classLoader)
              .load(classLoader, ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER_PERSISTENT)
              .getLoaded();

      // Create the repository
      new ByteBuddy()
          .makeInterface(
              TypeDescription.Generic.Builder.parameterizedType(BaseRepository.class, entityClass)
                  .build())
          .name(def.getRepositoryClassName())
          .annotateType(
              AnnotationDescription.Builder.ofType(Repository.class)
                  .define("value", def.getRepositoryBeanName())
                  .build())
          .make()
          // .load(classLoader)
          .load(classLoader, ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER_PERSISTENT)
          .getLoaded();

      // This is an ugly hack in order to create the same BeanDefinition for
      // our created Repository as if it was auto configured by spring
      // boot. There is no other way (AFAIK) to do this, since Spring
      // won't scan the dynamically created classes. See:
      // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37402782
      // So the hack is to create a RootBeanDefinition from a known
      // existing repository RootBeanDefinition, and then to change
      // the argument that will be used to create the
      // JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.
      final RootBeanDefinition repositoryABeanDefinition =
          (RootBeanDefinition) beanFactory.getBeanDefinition("someRepositoryA");
      final RootBeanDefinition repositoryBeanDefinition =
          new RootBeanDefinition(repositoryABeanDefinition);
      repositoryBeanDefinition.getConstructorArgumentValues().clear();
      repositoryBeanDefinition
          .getConstructorArgumentValues()
          .addIndexedArgumentValue(0, def.getRepositoryClassName());
      ((DefaultListableBeanFactory) beanFactory)
          .registerBeanDefinition(def.getRepositoryBeanName(), repositoryBeanDefinition);

      // Create the service mapper
      final Class<?> mapperClass =
          new ByteBuddy()
              .subclass(
                  TypeDescription.Generic.Builder.parameterizedType(
                          BaseMapper.class, entityClass, dtoClass)
                      .build(),
                  ConstructorStrategy.Default.NO_CONSTRUCTORS)
              .name(def.getMapperClassName())
              .annotateType(
                  AnnotationDescription.Builder.ofType(Component.class)
                      .define("value", def.getMapperBeanName())
                      .build())
              .defineConstructor(Modifier.PUBLIC)
              .withParameters(SomeRepositoryA.class, SomeRepositoryB.class)
              .intercept(
                  MethodCall.invoke(
                          BaseMapper.class.getDeclaredConstructor(
                                  SomeRepositoryA.class, SomeRepositoryB.class))
                      .withArgument(0, 1))
              .make()
              // .load(classLoader)
              .load(classLoader, ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER_PERSISTENT)
              .getLoaded();

      final BeanDefinition mapperBeanDefinition = new RootBeanDefinition(mapperClass);
      ((DefaultListableBeanFactory) beanFactory)
          .registerBeanDefinition(def.getMapperBeanName(), mapperBeanDefinition);

      // Create the service interface
      final Class<?> serviceInterfaceClass =
          new ByteBuddy()
              .makeInterface(
                  TypeDescription.Generic.Builder.parameterizedType(
                          BaseService.class, entityClass, dtoClass)
                      .build())
              .name(def.getServiceInterfaceClassName())
              .make()
              //.load(classLoader)
               .load(classLoader, ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER_PERSISTENT)
              .getLoaded();

      // Create the service implementation
      final Class<?> serviceImplClass =
          new ByteBuddy()
              .subclass(
                  TypeDescription.Generic.Builder.parameterizedType(
                          BaseServiceImpl.class, entityClass, dtoClass)
                      .build(),
                  ConstructorStrategy.Default.NO_CONSTRUCTORS)
              .name(def.getServiceImplementationClassName())
              .implement(serviceInterfaceClass)
              .annotateType(
                  AnnotationDescription.Builder.ofType(Service.class)
                      .define("value", def.getServiceBeanName())
                      .build())
              .defineConstructor(Modifier.PUBLIC)
              .withParameter(BaseRepository.class)
              .annotateParameter(
                  AnnotationDescription.Builder.ofType(Autowired.class).build(),
                  AnnotationDescription.Builder.ofType(Qualifier.class)
                      .define("value", def.getRepositoryBeanName())
                      .build())
              .withParameter(SomeRepositoryA.class)
              .intercept(
                  MethodCall.invoke(
                          BaseServiceImpl.class.getDeclaredConstructor(
                                  BaseRepository.class, SomeRepositoryA.class))
                      .withArgument(0, 1))
              .make()
              //.load(classLoader)
              .load(classLoader, ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER_PERSISTENT)
              .getLoaded();

      final BeanDefinition serviceBeanDefinition = new RootBeanDefinition(serviceImplClass);
      ((DefaultListableBeanFactory) beanFactory)
          .registerBeanDefinition(def.getServiceBeanName(), serviceBeanDefinition);

      // Create the rest controller
      final Class<?> controllerClass =
          new ByteBuddy()
              .subclass(
                  TypeDescription.Generic.Builder.parameterizedType(
                          BaseController.class, entityClass, dtoClass)
                      .build(),
                  ConstructorStrategy.Default.NO_CONSTRUCTORS)
              .name(def.getControllerClassName())
              .annotateType(
                  AnnotationDescription.Builder.ofType(RestController.class)
                      .define("value", def.getControllerBeanName())
                      .build(),
                  AnnotationDescription.Builder.ofType(RequestMapping.class)
                      .defineArray("value", def.getControllerPath())
                      .build())
              .defineConstructor(Modifier.PUBLIC)
              .withParameter(BaseService.class)
              .annotateParameter(
                  AnnotationDescription.Builder.ofType(Autowired.class).build(),
                  AnnotationDescription.Builder.ofType(Qualifier.class)
                      .define("value", def.getServiceBeanName())
                      .build())
              .intercept(
                  MethodCall.invoke(
                          BaseController.class.getDeclaredConstructor(BaseService.class))
                      .withArgument(0))
              .make()
              //.load(classLoader)
              .load(classLoader, ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER_PERSISTENT)
              .getLoaded();

      final BeanDefinition controllerBeanDefinition = new RootBeanDefinition(controllerClass);
      ((DefaultListableBeanFactory) beanFactory)
          .registerBeanDefinition(def.getControllerBeanName(), controllerBeanDefinition);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
      throw new FatalBeanException("Unable to create beans for entity " + def.getEntityName(), ex);
    }
  }
```

Now, when I use `load(classLoader)`, I run into the Orika/Javassist problem. And when I use the `load(classLoader, ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER_PERSISTENT)` way, and exception is thrown by the `make()` call when creating the service implementation class:

```
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type com.example.FooDtoA not present
```

Maybe it is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34219180) ? For now my solution is to create the DTO class the same way the Entity class is, and use the `load(classLoader)`. But I would like to generate the DTO class the same way all the other classes are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javassist probably relies on locating class files to do its work. With Byte Buddy, this is not necessarily possible as class files are injected such that a class loader cannot locate a class file from a jar file using the `.getResource` API.

Have you tried `.load(classLoader, ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER_PERSISTENT)`? This strategy retains the class file such that Javassist could locate it.

Comment: Thanks! Sadly it didn't work. I ran into another problem. I just edited my original question in order to explain in details what is this new problem, and what I try to do exactly.